# nokogiri xpath attribute - strange results

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a bunch of fields and when I try to run:

```
src.xpath('//RECORD').each do |record|
tbegin = record.xpath('//FIELD/TOKEN')
```

the `tbegin` array returns the fields from other records. I've checked that the first line is giving me the appropriate array of "record" subtrees, but the next call for `tbegin` doesn't limit the search to just the "record" subtree. In fact, it consistently returns the field subtree of `record[0]`.

Thus far, I've gotten around this by using:

```
tbegin = record.css('TOKEN')
```

but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: can you display the data which you want to parse

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the leading double-slash in `xpath('//FIELD/TOKEN')`, which tells nokogiri to match nodes not relative to this node, but across the whole document regardless of location. To match relative to the node itself, you have to remove the double-slash:

```
tbegin = record.xpath('FIELD//TOKEN')
```

Comment: Or, if you want to find all `FIELD` that are anywhere below the record, use `record.xpath('.//FIELD')`

Comment: One thing to mention, I used a double-slash in `'FIELD//TOKEN'`, which matches a `TOKEN` at any depth within `FIELD`. Without seeing the actual HTML it's hard to say what matcher is best, but if `TOKEN` is a direct child of `FIELD`, then one slash would also work.

Comment: For a node-specific search, you can also omit the initial "./". Nokogiri will default to node-specific search unless you explicitly tell it otherwise (as in the above example).

Answer (score 1):

As additional clarification, the reason `tbegin = record.css('TOKEN')` works is `record` is providing the top node where the search will begin. `'TOKEN'` doesn't force a search at the root of the document, unlike `//FIELD/TOKEN`, which would do that.